# Как сделать словарь на разных языках?

Tags: c#, unity3d, словари

Я недавно начал делать игры(если их можно так назвать) на unity. У меня возник вопрос. Как сделать словарь на разных языках. Например, я хочу, чтобы у меня в игре было 700 одинаковых по значению слов , но на пяти разных языках(например:кошка-cat- и тд)
Изначально человек выбирает два языка, один тот, который он знает, а другой тот, который хочет попрактиковать. И ему нужно соотнести слова по значению, например: выбран русский как основной и английский как второй язык.
И в процессе игры ему нужно решить задачу :
Соотнести слово(все та же кошка)
С его значением на английском:
Кошка - chair/sofa/dog/cat.
Все эти слова будут записаны в игре на всех языках, но я не знаю как их соотносить, да и в целом как сделать «базу» этих слов. Помогите

Answer (score 0):

```
[{
   'id':'cat',
   'en':'cat',
   'ru':'кот'
},
{
   'id':'dog',
   'en':'dog',
   'ru':'собака'
}]
```

пример бд в json. Рисуй в интерфейсе слова и сравнивай по id. Вопрос не имеет отношения к Unity.

Comment: Спасибо за оперативность

Answer (score 0):

Я использовал бы csv-таблицу, а так же какой-нибудь ассет для юнити для локализаций, который бы поддерживал бы работу с csv и импортирование/экспортирование в том числе (некоторые поддерживают только редактирование в юнити)

Ассетов по локализации достаточно много даже среди бесплатных: https://assetstore.unity.com/tools/localization?category=tools%2Flocalization&free=true&orderBy=1

Создай тестовый проэкт, покачай бесплатные, поиграйся и выбери что-то что подойдет по удобству, а потом интегрируй в свой проэкт

А править такую таблицу будет весьма удобно используя банальный ексель